# jquery opacity problems with fadein and fadeout

Tags: jquery

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/921159/desktopography/index.html

I'm building a wallpaper blog and trying to use jquery to show/hide a download link (I'm a newbie). The problem is, if you hover over the image and let the link fade in, then quickly hover off and back on while it's fading out... the link will stop at the opacity it's currently at. It ends up being a problem when a user casually hovers over the images and the opacity gets stuck at 0. Whats causing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`clearQueue` in the animation `.stop()` method defaults to `false` ([see API](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)) but you want it to be `true` because you want the current animation to clear and have it start the new hover state animation.  Change your code as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('.wallpaper').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('p').stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);   
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('p').stop(true, true).fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a result of the fact that you're using [`stop()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to halt the animation and reverse it. Trouble is that the next fade function *remembers* the stopped point, and uses that.

You can use [`fadeTo()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)  instead so you can fix the opacity targets at `1` and `0`.

```
$('.wallpaper').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('p').stop().fadeTo(300, 1);   
}, function() {
    $(this).children('p').stop().fadeTo(400 ,0);
});
```

---

**EDIT:** The equivalent using [`animate()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)  is:

```
$('.wallpaper').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('p').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 300);   
}, function() {
    $(this).children('p').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 400);   
});
```

Note that neither of these will set `display:none` at the end. If you want that, you'll need to do it manually.

```
$('.wallpaper').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('p').show().stop().fadeTo(300, 1);   
}, function() {
    $(this).children('p').stop().fadeTo(400 ,0, function(){$(this).hide()});
})
  .children('p').css('opacity',0);
```

Comment: This is an absolutely fantastic comment.  I was having a similar fade in/out issue, and your ideas solved the issue perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I prefer this because he cites alternatives!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.  It's designed to fix these issues.

Comment: OP is already using `stop()`. That's the *cause* of the problem.

Comment: @patrick dw - you're right.  But I think if he had added .stop(true, true) i think that would fix it.

Comment: Yes, that would keep it from getting stuck, but it also jumps to the end of the animation, giving a jarring effect. I'm guessing OP doesn't want that.